# Jquery Mobile Div's height not adjusting (or scrolling) automatically

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Hello here is my html code. What I am basically trying is:

1-User pastes some contents inside textaea id="tArea"

2-When he clicks on a button named "Done", the contents of textarea are asigned to div's inner html having id="tDiv"

3-The Div discussed applied a different font family to the contents of it (using css3 and it's perfectly working), but when the user's data get large, the **div is not able to either provide a scrollbar or adjust it's height automatically.**

Please Help, I have consumed many many hours but I'm still lost!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
<link rel=stylesheet href="resources/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="resources/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="resources/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Donegal One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fontfile.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.hindi, textarea {

font-family: 'Donegal One', serif !important;
overflow:auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
</style>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role=page id=sendMoneyWin data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme="c" >
            <h1>Font Changer</h1>
        </div>      
        <div data-role=content>
        <script>

            function transformFont(){
                $("#tDiv").html($("#tArea").attr("value"));
                //$("#tArea").css("display","none");
                $("#tArea").prop("readonly",true);
                $("#tDiv").css("display","block");
                $("#doneBtn").css("display","none");
                $("#reloadBtn").css("display","inline");
            }
            function clearAllAndReload(){
                $("#tDiv").html("");
                $("#tArea").attr("value","")
                //$("#tArea").css("display","block");
                //$("#tDiv").css("display","none");
                $("#tArea").prop("readonly",false);
                $("#doneBtn").css("display","inline");
                $("#reloadBtn").css("display","none");
            }
        </script>
        <b>Please paste the contents here, in the below text box :</b><br />
        <span id="reloadBtn" style="display:none;"><input type="button" value=" Reload " onClick="clearAllAndReload()" data-inline=true/></span>
        <span id="doneBtn" ><input type="button" value=" Done " onClick="transformFont()"  data-inline=true /></span>


        <textarea id="tArea" class="hindi" style="" ></textarea>
        <div id="tDiv" class="hindi" data-scroll='true' style="white-space: pre-wrap;overflow:visible;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;display:none;"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role=footer data-theme="c">
            <span style="float:right;"><small>Created & Maintained by TechBhardwaj, 2012&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small></span>
        </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried overflow:scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic css, div want behave as a re-sizable container unless you give it its dimensions.

This will work for you, remove all div styles and add it to a style block:

I. Add an overflow: scroll to div and remove it from style:

```
#tDiv {
    /* SCROLL FIX */
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;   
    overflow:scroll;
    /* END FIX */
    background: #aabbcc;
    white-space:
    pre-wrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    display:none;        
}
```

This will give you a scrollbar. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DMqX7/

II. Make it resizable:

```
#tDiv {
    /* RESIZE FIX */
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;   
    min-height: 200px;
    height:auto !important;        
    /* END FIX */
    background: #aabbcc;
    white-space:
    pre-wrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    display:none;        
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/aq8K3/